# Writing ASCII Values Into the Register of Serial Communication Devices Like RS485

Tags: java, modbus, serial-communication, rs485, easy-modbus

I am creating a java Desktop Application. I want to write the data into the register of a device. As per my project document, size of the register is 16-bit long. I am using EasyModbusJava jar to write data into the register. Till now I have written some integer data on the device's register. Now I want to write the ascii of 32 characters at 16 consecutive  register(2 Character per Register). But issue is that the available methods for writing on the registers takes int as an argument. If am passing the short(int) array of ascii values then it needs to be typecast which means that it will no longer be acquiring the size of the short data type.

There are **two methods are available to write into the registers address.**

**For Writing at Single Register**

```
public void WriteMultipleRegisters(int startingAddress, int[] values){...}
```

**For Writing at Multiple Register**

```
public void WriteMultipleRegisters(int startingAddress, int[] values){...}
```

Suggest some way to resolve my issue.

Below is the link of the jar file documentation which I am using in my project.
[Docs of Jar File.](http://www.easymodbustcp.net/javadoc/javadoc/index.html)

Comment: I didn't get it.

Comment: Probably only the lowest 16bits of each  int are used

Answer (score 0):

I ***think*** the easiest thing to do is use a [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) to manage this byte manipulation. Something like,

```
char[] arr = "Hello, World".toCharArray();
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(arr.length);
for (char ch : arr) {
    bb.put((byte) ch);
}
bb.rewind();
// You may need a call to ByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder) here.
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++) {
    int v = bb.getShort(); // Reads two bytes and converts to 16-bit short integer
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

Comment: The first method does not accept the array of integer.  It was my misket.  public void WriteMultipleRegisters(int startingAddress, int values){...}

Comment: Are the values returned by bb.getshort() are ascii?

Comment: @KetanSachan No. Because it is 2 8-bit ascii characters as 1 16-bit short integer. Exactly like you asked for.